# How do you close a dialog fragment and the fragment currently Opened without closing the entire app?

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment

I've tried This code:
Activity?.onBackPressed()
This only closes the app

Comment: To dismiss a `DialogFragment`, [call `dismiss()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/DialogFragment#dismiss()). We do not know what "the fragment currently Opened" means, because your question does not contain a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm kinda new to this. dismiss() only closes the dialog fragment, how do I close the dialog fragment and the fragment used to open the dialog fragment. I hope I make sense

Comment: We do not know how you set up "the fragment used to open the dialog fragment", because your question does not contain a [mcve]. As the one answer suggests, if you set up that fragment with a `FragmentTransaction`,  you can remove that fragment with a `FragmentTransaction`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try:

```
    activity.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(this).commit()
```